# Pandas profiling not able to import due to error 'cannot import name "DataError' from 'pandas.core.base'"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-profiling

I have just upgraded Python to 3.11 today. Pandas-profiling worked fine before, but now I cannot seem to import it due to the following error:

```
cannot import name 'DataError' from 'pandas.core.base' (C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py)
```

Any help as to how I can fix this?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Pandas version - 1.5.2
Pandas-profiling version - 3.2.0

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pandas_profiling`?

Comment: @alibakhtiari Yes Pandas_profiling is successfully installed

Comment: New name with new functionality btw ydata-profiling `pip install -U ydata-profiling`

Answer (score 5):

Schedule for deprecation

- ydata-profiling was launched in February 1st.
- pip install pandas-profiling will still be supported until April 1st,
  but a warning will be thrown. "from pandas_profiling import
  ProfileReport "  will be supported until April 1st.
- After April 1st, an error will be thrown if pip install
  pandas-profiling is used. Use pip install ydata-profiling instead.
- After April 1st, an error will be thrown if from pandas_profiling
  import ProfileReport is used. Use from ydata_profiling import
  ProfileReport instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You need to simply install the `ydata_profiling` package and also `pandas_profiling`; after that, type:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

After more research, I think this is an issue with the new version of python (3.11).
I re-installed python 3.10(.9) and pandas_profiling works perfectly fine.

The code to run this different version of python in Jupyter notebook from cmd shell is:

```
C:\Users\User_name\Your_path_to_python\Python\Python310\python.exe -m notebook
```

Then just use pandas_profiling normally.
If anyone has any suggestions to get it working on python v3.11, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In case you found a bug in a library, you may want to report it directly to the maintainers, so they get aware and provide a fix. In your case, please follow the instructions on https://pandas-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/support_contrib/help_troubleshoot.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update Version as of 2024:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import ydata_profiling as pp
```

`pandas_profiling` is no longer maintained: https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/. Instead, according to the instructions, you should use `ydata_profiling`.