# I am unable to import csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, analytics, data-analysis

I am facing an issue regarding in python , when I import the csv file in python it is showing the data in VSCode. means file is running and successfully imported but when I want to create a report of same csv file by using from **pandas_profiling import ProfileReport** it shows me an error code and error mentioned:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
print(df)

profile = ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_file(output_file ="housing.html")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RDcO.png)

I want to generate **Pandas Profiling Report **

Comment: Check out this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996550/pandas-profiling-not-able-to-import-due-to-error-cannot-import-name-dataerror). Does it fix your error?

Comment: Also, please [do not upload picture of your code or tracebacks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), instead provide the traceback as code, it makes it easier to look at.

Comment: HI @Ftagliacarne thankyou for replying , but the reference link not working in this case

Comment: You are importing from pandas_profiling, but the repo states that you should be importing from ydata_profiling instead. Does that solve your problem? What error codes do you get?

Comment: ydata_profiling? i dont know how to modify in this code.

Comment: @SaeedAhsan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996550/pandas-profiling-not-able-to-import-due-to-error-cannot-import-name-dataerror

Comment: In any case, it seems like there might be an issue between pandas profiling and python3.11. https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/issues/1237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error i can guess you have some environment issues. The code you have written is errorless. Run your code in colab and you should see the results.

Comment: No i have already added the environment variables , each service updated. But i am unable to resolve this issue.